# How to open virtual machines in tabs in VMware Workstation 14?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have 3 different operating system as virtual machine and I want to switch between them in tabs, not different VMware Workstation windows. Is it possible?

By the way I am using VMware Workstation as free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you're using the *free* version of VMware Workstation, it means that you're actually using VMware Workstation *Player*, not VMware Workstation *Pro*. (There no longer is a product called just "VMware Workstation".) The Pro version already uses tabs.  Player does not support tabs.